# Android Databinding: how to get field value of kotlin enum class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have an enum class with two fields:

```
enum class MyEnum(val text1: String, val text2: String) {
    A("a1", "a2"),
    B("b1", "b2")
}
```

And I want to use that field values in XML with databinding. My ViewModel provides an `ObservableField<MyEnum>` which schould be used in XML via databinding:

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val myEnum = ObservableField<MyEnum>(MyEnum.A)
}
```

I try to read the field value in XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="com.example.MyEnum" />

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.example.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="@{vm.myEnum.text1}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

but I get the following exception:
Cannot find the setter for attribute 'text' with parameter string

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using `@={}` instead of `@{}` for the data binding expression?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, just checked again: I use `@{}` syntax

Comment: That's odd, as I do not know why data binding would need a setter in this case.

Comment: Is that typo 'andoid:text' just in this post ?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo only in post

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Late for answer, but have you tried using `BindingAdapter`

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("yourTitleText")
fun fetchYourTitleText(view: TextView, type: MyEnum) {
    view.apply {
        text = when (type) {
            MyEnum.A -> "Your value for A"
            MyEnum.B -> "Your value for B"
        }
    }
}
```

and in `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="com.example.MyEnum" />
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.example.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            app:yourTitleText="@{vm.myEnum}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```